# Handle Websphere Multiple Queue Managers In Java

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am attempting to read / write from Websphere Multiple Queue Managers QM1, QM2 and so on. Each queue manager have own channel id and multiple queues under each QM.

Is it possible to write java code for these conditions.

I wrote java code for multiple queues under one QM by looping queues one by one and process them. but even i cannot think to code for multiple QM. If anybody have idea please share me.

Comment: Can you please explain the need for connecting to multiple queue managers in one application? What is the business case?

Comment: Good morning Shasi.. Thank you for your response. It is for future use.
Business case is, client will put messages in each QM / Queues from their channels like IB, Mobile banking etc. we need to process their messages and write corresponding responses to another MQ / Queues.
Can you please explain me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have that sort of requirement then you may want to do this:

Run multiple instances of your consumer application where each instance connects to a dedicated queue manager and process messages. Run multiple threads with each thread processing messages from their dedicated queue.

This way the message processing load is distributed across multiple instances and failure in one application does not affect others.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Shashi.. Mutiple instances means you are mentioning multiple Start Listner program. Now i have one main class inside that startListener method is there.. startListener method have infinite loop it will look every time MQ and call process. so i need to write multiple main class right.